# Page changing even with unsuccessful auth

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I have this simple method right here that attempts to sign in a user and then if successful, will route the user to the ProfileSetupPage.

```
async onLogin(user: User){
    try {
      const result = this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
      if (result){
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(ProfileSetupPage);
      }
    }catch (e){
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

If I attempt to log in, I get the Runtime Error message, 'there is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted' which is good, however when I close out of this - the user was still redirected to the ProfileSetupPage. Since the result was obviously false, why would it execute the this.navCtrl.setRoot method?

Newbie angular/ionic coder here - help on this would be greatly appreciated! Also, is there a way to show a message if not succesful instead of the Runtime Error overlay? Thanks!!

Comment: Could you show us what's inside of `afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword`

Comment: @JohnVelasquez this is a firebase method, not something I have written. Comes from the AnfularFireAuth import

Comment: @JohnVelasquez If you are really interested, see [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signInWithEmailAndPassword)

Comment: Try try {
      const result = await this.afAuth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its returning a `Promise`

You should do this instead

and add the `catch` base on the their documentation its throwing the error.

```
async onLogin(user: User){
    const result = this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then((res) =>{
     this.navCtrl.setRoot(ProfileSetupPage);
    })
    .catch((error) =>{  console.error(error);});
}
```